# Error while installing iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: ios, macos, installation

I tried installing iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 on my Mac
[image]

While installing at first I got this warning but I continued anyway

[image]

Which got me to this. 
Please help me to install the iPhone Configuration Utility.

I have a macOS High Sierra Version - 10.13.6 (17G65)

Comment: Why are you installing that version?  You should use Apple Configurator 2

Comment: In Mojave its not working anymore. Did you find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Command+Shift+G from the Mac OS X desktop.
2. Search Path  ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

This will list all your provisional profiles. To see detail - just select a provisional profile and hit the spacebar.

[image]